# How slow could handling iolist/deep list be than handling the flat list?

Tags: erlang

I see that [Erlang Efficiency User's Guide Section 5.3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html#id64686) recommends leaving the non-flat list as it is when being used as an iolist because the penalty of non-flattening is smaller than flattening.  Is there any quantitative example of the speed difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a deep list contains *n* elements, then performing `lists:flatten` on it will require Θ(*n*) time, and worse, Θ(*n*) memory allocations. How slow that is on your machine is a function of many variables; measure and ye shall know.

Comment: Thanks for the down-to-earth explanation.